# Notepad++ text Is always black except in the second view

Tags: notepad++, fonts

So recently I was messing with Windows theme settings (I'm on Windows 10) and I remembered an oldish trick that lets you change font colors to whatever you want with high contrast mode. I wanted to see if it was possible still so I went into high contrast mode and selected one of them to see the difference. It worked fine and I decided to switch it back to "None" but I discovered that Notepad++ has this weird font issue only in the "other view". (if you move stuff to another view) None of my other programs are effected and I tried resetting all of my Notepad++ settings but it did not fix the issue.

[image: No view]

[image: Other view]

Comment: "tried resetting all of my Notepad++ settings but it did not fix the issue." what have you tried?

Comment: I deleted all of the configuration files under %AppData%\Notepad++ (even the unrelated ones) and restarted notepad. It's not any plugins because I tried deleted them and it doesn't seem like it would related either. I have a feeling it could be fixed through regedit (idk how) or something... It seems like a windows problem.

Comment: can you try deleting `stylers.xml` from %AppData%/Roaming/Notepad++/ ?

Comment: I already tried doing that but it didn't fix it... I tried to reply but I guess my comment didn't send... Sorry lol.